# Euclid's proof (Variations)

Tags: solution-verification, prime-numbers, arithmetic

I have seen the following proof of Euclid's theorem:

[Euclid's proof  (Variations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem)

In the variant, they don't say it is $n$. Should I assume that $n$ is a natural number greater than $1% or should I assume that $n$ is any prime number?

Also found the following demo:

Given a number $n$, let's consider n! It is true that everything number less than or equal to $n$ divides $n!$, then no number less than or equal to that $n$ divides $n! + 1$. Consequently a prime divisor of $n! + 1$ must be greater than $n$. Therefore above every number $n$ there is always a number prime. This implies that there are infinitely many primes.

Again, in this new proof I've cited, should I assume that $n$ is a number greater than $1$ or a prime number?

Comment: In both cases, $n$ is a positive integer (which means it could itself be prime, but that is in fact irrelevant).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Why do you say that $n$ is a positive integer? From what I see in the demo, $n$ can be $0$. Here I am referring specifically to the second demonstration that I have cited.

Comment: If you knew that, why would you ask if it is assumed to be a prime? Yes, if you are comfortable with the empty product, you can take it to be $0$ as well in the first one. In the second one you would be saying it is divisible by $0$, which is false ("divisible by all integers from 1 to 0").

Comment: So, in the second case we need to specify that $n$ must be a positive integer, right?

Comment: It is assumed to be a positive integer. **You** were the one who was wondering if it was supposed to be *further* restricted, and then *objected* when I said "positive integer". Are you paying attention to what you are saying, or are you just trolling?

Answer (score 2):

It's proof by contradiction assuming that,

*There exists an integer n, such that n is the largest prime.*

See the book quoted from the [Euclid-Variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem#Variations),  Bostock, Linda; Chandler, Suzanne; Rourke, C. (2014-11-01). Further Pure Mathematics. Nelson Thornes. p. 168. ISBN 9780859501033.
[image]

While wiki page [Euclid-Variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem#Variations) doesn't give a full picture, but only mention that

*The factorial n! of **a positive integer n** is divisible by every integer from 2 to n, as it is the product of all of them.*

It would be better to have the above contradiction statement in the book, thus n starts from 2.

Comment: But what if $n$ were $1$, I don't see much point in mentioning that it is divisible from $2$ to $n$.

Comment: Yes, based on the contradiction statement that **There exists an integer n, such that n is the largest prime.**, n should be at least 2, which is the smallest prime.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $m$ is the largest prime.

Let $p_1, p_2, ..., p_n$ be primes less than $m$.

What is $q = (p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot ... \cdot p_n \cdot m) + 1$?  Is it not prime and is it not greater than $m$, the alleged "largest" prime?

Remember, it must be that for $q$ to be composite, $q$ is a unique product of nonzero powers of $p_1, p_2, ..., p_n$ i.e. it's at a minimum divisible by $p_1, p_2, ..., p_n, m$, but that isn't true (because of $+ 1$).

Comment: So, $p + 1$ is also prime. So for any number $p$ which is a unique product of primes, we can find another prime $p + 1$ such that $(p + 1) > p$. Isn't that how the proof works?

Comment: @peterwhy, changed my answer. Comments welcome